# How are random numbers assigned to a list or arrary?

Tags: python

```
aList = []
For i in range(6)
  Num=random.randint(1,6)
  aList.append(Num)
  print(aList)
```

Is giving output in pattern:

```
[2]
[4 ,6]
```

ETC.
But i want output in a single list.like
`[5,5,3,5,2,1]`

Comment: Unindent the `print` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.randint(0, 7, 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing inside the for loop.
content of list are OK.
Move the print statement to outside for loop.

```
import random
aList = []
for i in range(6):
    num=random.randint(1,6)
    aList.append(num)

print(aList)
```

Result

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
[5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4]
>>>
```